# ruby access instance variable in instance_eval

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, instance-variables, instance-eval

I am trying some ruby metaprogramming and got some confusion with instance_eval().

see below examples

```
@instance_var = 'instance_var'
local_var = 'local_var'
obj = Object.new
obj.instance_eval { p @instance_var; p local_var }
obj.instance_eval { @instance_var  = 'instance_var_in_obj'; local_var = 'local_var_in_obj' }
p @instance_var; p local_var
```

I expect both of @instance_var and local_var can be pass/modify in block but i got

```
nil
"local_var"
"instance_var"
"local_var_in_obj"
```

as result we can share(pass/modify) local vars in `instance_val` but instance vars are belong to `self` CAN NOT share.

and about `instance_exec`:

```
obj.instance_exec(@instance_var) {|instance_var| p instance_var; instance_var = @instance_var }
=> "instance_var"
@instance_var
=> "instance_var"
```

now i can pass my outer instance var and still CAN NOT modify it.

```
@instance_arr = []
obj.instance_exec(@instance_arr) {|instance_arr| instance_arr << 'in_block' }
@instance_arr
=> ["in_block"]
obj.instance_exec(@instance_arr) {|instance_arr| instance_arr = [] }
@instance_arr
=> ["in_block"]
```

with a instance var of array i can modify my instance var but ONLY within current array object

in summary play `instance_eval` or `instance_exec` with local vars not instance vars?

is there some concepts i missed?

Comment: I can offer 1/2 of an answer. You have two instance variables named @instance_var, one for an instance of `Object` we call `main` and the other `obj`.Within the block of `obj.instance_eval { p @instance_var; p local_var }`, `self` is `obj` and `@instance_var` for that object has not been initialized, so it returns `nil` when referenced. I don't fully understand why the local variable is treated differently, but I suspect it has to do with the fact that referencing an initialized local variable raises an exception.

Comment: thank you for answer,  about  `@instance_var` the `@` says that you belongs to somebody i think i can understand this part and yes the point of my question is `why the local variable is treated differently` or `local variables` actually belongs to what how to think it in scope??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search and advices from my friend i think i figured out the problem.
In ruby there is two `Context` when your code running `self` and `binding`, when you work with `local vars` or `method` without set `self.xxx` first thing will be checking is it in your `binding` object as a `local var` if not Ruby will think it's a method then search on your `self` object to find its definition and invoke it.
Think this:

```
class A
  def test
    4
  end
  def use_variable
    test = 5
    test
  end
  def use_method
    test = 5
    self.test
  end
end
a = A.new
a.use_variable # returns 5
a.use_method   # returns 4
```

That's explained `WHY` of `instance_eval` as its document said `instance_eval` just changed `self` in the given block and NOT touch `binding` so methods will be search on new `self`, local vals still in same `binding` object.

About `instance_exec` i'm not very sure about this but seems like instance vars(with at prefix vars) it will be search on `self` directly skip on `binding`, so out of `instance_exec` your `@instance_arr` belongs to old `self` and in `instance_exec` block you got it as a new `local var` in the new `binding` of block(block has own scope) but the value of it actually is the reference of `@instance_arr` so invoke method on the new `local var` such like `push` it will change both of them because they share same `Array instance`, but when you assign a new `Array instance` to the new `local var` they are no longer refer same `Array instance` that's the second `WHY`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to evaluate the local variable, you would need to pass in the string `"local_var" and it will return the value of the local variable.  If you pass in a block, then an argument can not be passed in, according to my interpretation of [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval).

The behavior of instance eval in the block form is to access as a closure the instance variables and private methods of the object where that call is.

The behavior of instance eval with an argument allows you to evaluate a string in the scope of that call.

Comment: thank you for answer, your interpretation is right i just missed `binding` concept in mind it can explain the problem. :)